# Unable to get/set variable that should be in scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out why the `access_token` (function) variable isn't accessible from an inner scope (ie. nested inside of the global function).

Here is the code:

```
$(function () {

            var accessToken = "";

            var getHeaders = function () {
                alert(accessToken);
                if (accessToken) {
                    return {
                        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken
                    };
                }
            }

            var showResponse = function (obj) {

                $("#output").text(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4));

            };

            var register = function () {
                var url = "/api/account/register";
                var contentBody = $("#registerData").serialize();

                $.post(url, contentBody).always(showResponse);
                return false;
            }

            var saveAccessToken = function (response) {
                accesToken = response.access_token;
            };

            var login = function () {
                var url = "/token";
                var contentBody = $("#loginData").serialize();
                contentBody = contentBody + "&grant_type=password";
                $.post(url, contentBody)
                    .success(saveAccessToken)
                    .always(showResponse);

                return false;
            };

            var getPatients = function () {
                var url = "http://localhost:62012/api/patients/";
                $.ajax(url, {
                    type: "GET",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken); }
                }).always(showResponse);

                return false;

            };

            $("#getPatients").click(getPatients);
            $("#register").click(register);
            $("#login").click(login);
        });
```

I've attempted to use alerts throughout the code, but it would seem as if the `accessToken` simply is `""` whenever the alert isn't fired **inside** `saveAcessToken`...

**General flow of the application:**

1. User logs in, sets the `accessToken`.
2. An `ajax` **GET** request is sent when the user clicks the `getPatients` button.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are most likely trying to access the variable before the AJAX call is complete.

Comment: See the edit in "general flow". It shouldn't be possible for the variable not to be set when I'm sending the request over since the variable **SHOULD** be set after the `login`. :/

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are setting a variable named accesToken in saveAccessToken. Try renaming it to accessToken